# Is it legal to bring a Jamon Iberico from Spain into the UK, passing through France?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, france, spain, england

I have not tried this in the past, but I am guessing that since all countries involved are part of the EU, it should be possible.

I am planning to fly from Barcelona to Paris, after which I will take the Eurostar to London. Will there be any point on the way where I might suffer any problems during the import?

Comment: What is a "Jamon Iberico"?

Comment: Literally, a Spanish ham.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do that. That's precisely what the single market is about and, incidentally, the reason why the EU enacts so many seemingly petty unrelated rules (EU countries have to agree on rules regarding safety, labelling, etc. so that most products can then circulate freely between them instead of setting rules independently of each other and enforcing those rules at the border).

Information provided on the [gov.uk website](https://www.gov.uk/personal-food-plant-and-animal-product-imports) reflects this:

> If you’re travelling from a country within the EU, you can bring any fresh foodstuffs - fruit, vegetables, meat, dairy or other animal products (eg fish, eggs and honey) - into the UK.

(This being based on EU law, French rules will be similar.)

The only exceptions to this general principle are things like firearms and drugs, for which rules haven't been harmonized. Even alcohol or tobacco can be carried between countries relatively freely, provided it is for your personal use (quantitative thresholds [like those found on gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/duty-free-goods/arrivals-from-eu-countries) are only guidelines based on the notion that very large quantities are not for personal use).

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can import some meat (including ham) to the UK from Spain, going through France. Both France and the UK have documents provided by their customs on the topic about food imports:

- [UK customs](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http%3A%2F%2Fcustoms.hmrc.gov.uk%2FchannelsPortalWebApp%2FdownloadFile%3FcontentID%3DHMCE_PROD_010856)
- [French customs](http://www.douane.gouv.fr/Portals/0/fichiers/datadouane/publication-douane/particuliers/banned-and-authorised-foodstuffs-entering-eu.pdf)